# Run Group at the end of a Suite

Tags: selenium, testng

I have the following doubt using groups and dependencies on my testng.xml

I need to run a group of methods at the end of the suite (these methods are test cases for removing data that was created on other test cases).
So first I have a test excluding group "removed", and then I have a test just including this group "removed".

Example:

```
<test name="Test1" preserve-order="true" >
        <groups>
            <run>
                <exclude name="removed" />
            </run>
        </groups>
        <classes>
                <class name="class1"/>
        </classes>
</test>

<test name="Remove" preserve-order="true" >
        <groups>
            <run>
                <include name="removed" />
            </run>
        </groups>
</test>
```

The thing is... in class1 I have methods belonging to removed group.
Why "Remove" test is not executed?
This is a small example, but removed group contains methods from a lot of classes that are ran at the beginning.
I am using Selenium with Testng 6.8
Thanks!

Comment: Please add tags and context informing the community of which tools you are using in your testing suite. We need more context to be able to help you accurately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding classes, packages and methods tells TestNG where to look for tests. By defining them you're saying, "Hey TestNG, this is where I keep all my tests."

When you specify groups, you're telling TestNG to pick out specific subsets of your tests.

In your `Test1` test when you specify `exclude name="removed"` you're letting TestNG know to skip anything in that group. So your final state for `Test1` is to look inside `class1` for all your test cases, but to exclude any of the group `removed`.

In your `Removed` test when you say to `include name="removed"` you're letting TestNG know that it should now run those tests.

Comment: Thanks mvolkhart, now is working. I understood how it works. :D